# issue in dispaly text in webview with bold and make new line android

Tags: android, webview

Hello friends i have one text value which content bold, normal style so i write this text in my string.xml file like below

```
<string name="setting_messages">
  <![CDATA[
   <b>Default Selection</b><br>
   <p>My TEXT</p> <br>

    <b>Deleted Property</b>  <br>
    <p>MyText</p><br>


    <b>Upgrade Package</b> <br>
    <p>1. Line one.</p><br>
   <p>2. Line Two.</p><br>


  ]]></string>
```

in my java file i call web view like below

```
String formattedText = getString(R.string.setting_messages);
                Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(formattedText);

                String htmlText = "<html><body style=\"text-align:center\">"+result+"  </body></Html>";


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Help");

                WebView wv = new WebView(getActivity());
                wv.loadData(String.format(htmlText, result), "text/html", "utf-8");
                alertDialogBuilder

                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }) ;

                alertDialogBuilder.setView(wv);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
```

When i run above code it is coming like below as a output
[image]

In this image it is not take bold ,and br tag in web view any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
String htmlText = "<html><body style=\"text-align:center\">"+result+"  </body></Html>";
```

is effectively the same as:

```
String htmlText = "<html><body style=\"text-align:center\">"+result.toString()+"  </body></Html>";
```

Calling toString() on a Spannable object will remove all the formatting. This is where you are losing your bold text and newlines.

You can format the string like this without converting to a Spannable first:

```
String htmlText = "<html><body style=\"text-align:center\">"+formattedText+"  </body></Html>";
```

Then pass it directly to the WebView:

```
wv.loadData(htmlText, "text/html", "utf-8");
```